# reduce the size of the winsxs directory and free up disk space on windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I using `Windows Server 2012 Datacenter` and `C:\Windows\WinSxS` is *HUGE*, so I looked and found following article: [How to Reduce the Size of the Winsxs directory and Free Up Disk Space on Windows Server 2012 Using Features on Demand - Ask Premier Field Engineering (PFE) Platforms - Site Home - TechNet Blogs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/02/24/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2012-using-features-on-demand.aspx), unfortunately that doesn't really help me, as features that I have installed are actually in use.

What are my other options? How else can I reduce that folder?

Answer (score -2):

[How to Reduce the Size of the WinSxS directory and Free Up Disk Space on Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1 or do we even need to? - Ask Premier Field Engineering (PFE) Platforms - Site Home - TechNet Blogs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2015/02/09/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2012-r2-and-windows-8-1-or-do-we-even-need-to.aspx)

Look at /ResetBase

This is a great command added with Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2.  Essentially, it’s the mother of all commands. It cleanups and removes all the old superseded stuff from every component in the component store.

Comment: Per my original question, I'm using `Windows Server 2012 Datacenter` and _NOT_ using `Windows Server 2012 R2`.